# How to check a class is a leaf class (No Descendent classes) in C# in an EFFICIENT way?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am using the following code and found the efficiency is very low for I call the function very often.

```
public static bool IsLeafType(this Type type)
{
    try
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                      .SelectMany(p => p.GetTypes())
                                      .Any(p => p.IsSubclassOf(type));
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course, a sealed class is a leaf class, but maybe a non sealed class has no subclasses also.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why are you trying to achieve this?  While it's a valid question it's a very unusual approach and perhaps the wrong solution to whatever you're trying to solve.

Comment: At least you can cache `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` after the point you believe no more assemblies will be loaded.

Comment: So this code works but you think it's inefficient... and it may well be, but what have you measured to determine this? Is it actually a bottleneck? If not, it may not matter. Finally, what have you tried to make it more efficient?

Comment: You can cache the whole tree too... but there really no way to guarantee that particular non-sealed class does not have descendants. Especially in some dynamic environment like ASP.Net where pages derive from base classes after process starts... As @abatishchev said without details about what you want to achieve it is hard to give correct and concrete answer.

Comment: I don't get it. You'll return `true` if the type you're testing has a subclass. The opposite of a leaf class.

Comment: @spender OP also returns "true" when anything happened during type enumeration which is quite common (and in some configurations of assemblies 100% guaranteed)... so it is either very lax definition of "leaf" or more likely just very simplified sample based on real code.

Comment: Thank you all at first.
Let me clarify.

Comment: Thank you all at first.
Let me clarify. For example,
1. I have a Gridview to show IList<T> in a master-detail way. For each object in IList<T>, I will show how many detail (collection properties) in this object. So that user may check the detail further.
2. At design time, I know type T, but in case other developers create subclass of type T. I have to make my solution flexible.

Comment: 3. In case the IList<T> has many (maybe millions) objects, I am thinking to check the properties of type T only for a leaf class (without descendant classes) and check  the properties of every object when type T is not a leaf class. I hope this will improve the performance.
 
So I created the function IsLeafType().

Answer (score 0):

If my calculations are correct, this will make a lazily evaluated hashset that contains all leaf classes the first time you call it. Subsequent calls are a speedy lookup in the hashset.

```
void Main()
{
    var a = typeof(TextWriter).IsLeafType(); //false
    var b = typeof(StreamWriter).IsLeafType(); //true
}

static class Ex
{
    private static Lazy<ISet<Type>> typeSetLazy =
        new Lazy<ISet<Type>>(() => {
            var types = AppDomain
                        .CurrentDomain
                        .GetAssemblies()
                        .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()
                                          .Where(t=>t.IsClass));
            var typesAndBaseTypes = types
                                    .Select(t => new { Type = t, t.BaseType })
                                    .ToList();
            var typesWithSubclasses = typesAndBaseTypes
                                        .Join(
                                            typesAndBaseTypes,
                                            t => t.Type,
                                            t => t.BaseType,
                                            (t1, t2) => t2.BaseType);
            var typesHs = new HashSet<Type>(types);
            typesHs.ExceptWith(typesWithSubclasses);
            return typesHs;
        });
    public static bool IsLeafType(this Type type)
    {
        return typeSetLazy.Value.Contains(type);
    }
}
```

...of course, the cache is only valid at the time it was created.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is much better than mine in performance.
If no easy function to do so, I will use your solution.
Thank you very much.